# Site Map Menu are not translatable

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have created sitemap page using [sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map) module to include some menu for displaying on sitemap page. Now I am unable to translate menu titles, while all the links are translated.
Also I added the translation for menu title from Edit-Menu-> Translate.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the [Main Menu not translated](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092160) issue, which states:

> When using the default 'Main menu' menu, and outputting that on the sitemap, the title, or menu name, isn't translated ...

I just double checked in a multi language site also where I have the **[i18n Menu Translation](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/i18n/tree/i18nmenu)** sub-module enabled (one of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) sub-modules).

I tried editing the Sitemap menu item to be translated, by navigating to admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation. From there I tried to use the "translate" link (for the Sitemap menu item), which one would expect that it can be used to **translate** that menu item.

However, after doing so, I only get something like "You are not authorized to access this page."

This issue appears to be fixed in [the most recent dev version](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092160#comment-5958286).